# Getting different results for regionprops in matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab

Im converting a matlab code to python to simulate in ros.While dealing with regionprops in both,matlab and python is showing different results for only some arrays.For remaining arrays,both are showing same results.

Here is my matlab code:

```
Z = ones(1000,1000);
c = [17.49;0;0;1000;1000;17.49];
c1 = [0;17.49;38;0;0];
r = [30.37;45.12;1000;1000;348.55;30.37];
r1 = [45.12;30.37;0;0;45.12];          
BW = roipoly(Z,c,r);
GI = mat2gray(BW);
s = regionprops(BW, GI, {'Centroid'});
BW1 = roipoly(Z,c1,r1);
GI1 = mat2gray(BW);
s1 = regionprops(BW1, GI1, {'Centroid'});
s.Centroid
s1.Centroid
```

Here is my python code to that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

c = np.array([[17.49,0,0,1000,1000,17.49],
              [0,17.49,38,0,0]])
r = np.array([[30.37,45.12,1000,1000,348.55,30.37],
              [45.12,30.37,0,0,45.12]])

X = c[0]
Y = r[0]
X1 = c[1]
Y1 = r[1]
mask = np.zeros((1000,1000),dtype = 'uint8')
mask1 = np.zeros((1000,1000),dtype = 'uint8')
rc = np.array((X,Y)).T
rc1 = np.array((X1,Y1)).T
cv2.drawContours(mask,[rc.astype(int)],0,255,-1)
cv2.drawContours(mask1,[rc1.astype(int)],0,255,-1)
for i in range(1000):
  for j in range(1000):
    if mask[i,j] ==255:
       mask[i,j] = 1
for i in range(1000):
  for j in range(1000):
    if mask1[i,j] ==255:
       mask1[i,j] = 1
out = np.zeros(mask.shape)
GI = cv2.normalize(mask, out, 1.0, 0.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
GI1 = cv2.normalize(mask1, out, 1.0, 0.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
GI = label(GI)
GI1 = label(GI1)
regions = regionprops(GI)
regions1 = regionprops(GI1)
for props in regions:
    y0, x0 = props.centroid
for props in regions1:
    y1, x1 = props.centroid
print(x0)
print(y0)
print(x1)
print(y1)
```

the result from matlab :

```
ans =
  467.4359  588.3356
ans =
   13.5307   16.3722
```

and the result from python is :

```
466.44296973332285
587.3801993195406
499.9950519678513
499.99219205932434
```

As you can see,with the first arrays regionprops producing the same result but with second arrays it is producing different result from matlab.Can you check this out for me ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `for props in regions: y0, x0 = props.centroid` -- this overwrites the output if you have more than one region. Why not just `y0, x0 = regions[0].centroid`?

Comment: You also might want to review what `cv2.normalize` does. I think you are inverting your image here. That would lead to a different centroid for sure!

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I found out the issue with this code.The problem is with label(GI).Instead of label,if we use np.squeeze both are giving same results.It is mentioned in label documentation that you can use np.squeeze instead.But i dont know why it is making such a huge difference.